# PHP Checkbox loop Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, each

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['feature'])){

   if(!empty($_POST['test'])){
    foreach($_POST['test'] as $selected){
    var_dump($_POST['test']);
      }
    }
  }

 ?>



<form action="" method="POST">
<?php
$query = $products->findAll();
 foreach($query as $row){
   if($row['featured'] == 'Yes'){
     echo "<label for='featured'>" . $row['p_name'] . " </label> <input type='checkbox' name='test[]' value = 'Yes' checked>";
   }
   else
   {
   echo "<label for='featured'>" . $row['p_name'] . " </label> <input type='checkbox' name='test[]' value ='No'>";
}
}
 ?>
 <input type="submit" name="feature" value="Feature">

 </form>
```

I have 5 products which is 'selected'. When I loop through to find what is selected I get 5 different arrays with 5 strings? I cant see where I've gone wrong, it should return 5 array's with just the one string of 'Yes' to show it's selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dumping the full array. You want:

```
var_dump($selected);
```